# Create array and output correct values

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm am dynamically creating elements with class "gmapItems". And I need to export an array of these elements for each.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="gmapItems">
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapCity" value='1'>
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapAddress" value='1'>
<textarea class="input-medium googleMapInformation" value='1'></textarea>
</div>

<div class="gmapItems">
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapCity" value='2'>
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapAddress" value='2'>
<textarea class="input-medium googleMapInformation" value='2'></textarea>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#AddGoogleMap").on('click', function () {            
    mapMarkers = new Array();
    $('.gmapItems').each(function(){
    gmapCity = $('.googleMapCity').val();
    gmapAddress = $('.googleMapAddress').val();
    gmapInfo = $('.googleMapInformation').val();  
    mapMarkers.push(gmapCity, gmapAddress, gmapInfo); 
    alert(mapMarkers)
    });
```

Comment: is there a push for multiple value  ? mapMarkers.push(gmapCity, gmapAddress, gmapInfo);

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You need to use `this` in `$('.googleMapCity',this).val()` to get `.googleMapCity` inside of current `.gmapItems`

```
$("#AddGoogleMap").on('click', function () {            
var mapMarkers = $('.gmapItems').map(function(){
       mapMarker = new Array();
       mapMarker.push($('.googleMapCity',this).val());
       mapMarker.push($('.googleMapAddress',this).val());
       mapMarker.push($('.googleMapInformation',this).val());  
       return mapMarker;
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for "this"! "This" made it all!